# Multiple AND condition not working in many to many table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table (t_user_state) in my database which is a junction table for many to many relationship, having values like this

| Userid | state |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | FL |
| 1 | CA |
| 2 | FL |
| 2 | AL |
| 2 | AK |

I want my sql query to return all users which have residential property in both state CA and FL getting in a comma seperated list like ('CA,FL'). So in this example it should return me only UserId=1. I tried with using IN operator but that is OR statement and returns UserId=2 too. I also tried with multiple AND like below but its not returning UserID=1 and returns nothing as one field or column cannot have 2 values at a same time.

```sql
select *
from t_recipe_course
where state='FL'
  and state='CA'
```

Can someone give me some hint or suggestions how to achieve this.

Comment: What details of the user do you want, just their ID, or the full row? Your query will never return any results as it's impossible for a scalar value (`state` in this case) to have different atomic values at the same time (`'FL'` and `'CA'` in your attempt).

Comment: @Larnu Just UserId will work for me. Yes I get that part that my query will not return that value but how to get the values which I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select userid
from t_recipe_course
where state in ('FL','CA')
group by userid 
having count(distinct state) = 2
```

Comment: Thanks your query works like a charm. It give me what I want exactly.

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @str as nvarchar(100)

set @str = 'FL,CA,AK'

select userid
from t_recipe_course as tc
inner join (select value from STRING_SPLIT(@str,',')) sp ON tc.state = sp.value
group by userid 
having count(distinct state) = (select count(*) from STRING_SPLIT(@str,','))
```

Comment: Can you please try this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One method is using a `HAVING` with a conditional aggregate:

```sql
SELECT userid
FROM dbo.t_recipe_course
GROUP BY userid
HAVING COUNT(CASE state WHEN 'FL' THEN 1 END) = 1
   AND COUNT(CASE state WHEN 'CA' THEN 1 END) = 1;
```

This *will* include people that have 3 (or more) residencies that include both FL and CA. If you want only those that have FL and CA and no others you could do this:

```sql
SELECT userid
FROM dbo.t_recipe_course
GROUP BY userid
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN state IN ('FL','CA') THEN state END) = 2
   AND COUNT(CASE WHEN state NOT IN ('FL','CA') THEN 1 END) = 0;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d168a8a799a8c4b2f84d0368accbf05b)

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I am getting a list of state as a parameter to my stored procedure as comma separated string like (FA,CA,AK) etc so states can be dynamic as per user selection. Can we achieve it like IN operator.

Comment: You can't parametrise an `IN` like that, no @ChupChapCharli . This statement *really* changes the question and should have been reflected in your question.

Comment: I tried your query and it did not work, returns nothing.

Comment: That would mean you have no users with both of the states in your real data, @ChupChapCharli . For the sample data you have provided, it does work: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d168a8a799a8c4b2f84d0368accbf05b)

Comment: if you will insert another record (1,'AL') to table then it will return nothing which is incorrect. I tried only 2nd query and you can check same.

Comment: *"
if you will insert another record (1,'CA') to table then it will return nothing which is incorrect "* Also not true for the second solution, @ChupChapCharli ... [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=8fd23b62919bb4f218f12fcf11d927f6)

Comment: Check my comment again.

Comment: And with your editted comment, note the statement I make above the solution: *" If you want **only** those that have FL and CA and **no others** you could do this:"* That is intentional....

Comment: It seems like your sample data, however, is not reflective of your real data, hence why it isn't working.